# Is possible to get the last string of an url as a param?

Tags: javascript, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, parameters

I cant get it with javascript URLSearchParams  function because it needs the "?" before.

Its possible to get the last string after last slash of an URL?

```
For ex: 
mydomain.com/hello
mydomain.com/otherExample
```

I need that "**hello**" be the param and stay in the index of my domain with the "param" value assigned to a var? Note that the "hello" page or directory doesn't exists.

Maybe is possible to manage it with the 404 error redirection?

Comment: What file/script are you expecting to handle the request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In .htaccess file you can redirect to your index without change the URL.

After, you must handle the window.location.pathname as they have told in other messages.

.htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.html
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to retrieve it with the following Javascript:

```
let parts = window.location.pathname.split('/');
let path = parts[parts.length - 1];
```

Comment: Thnx. But no file where write it, the url doesnt has ?, then redirect to the 404 error page.
Do u know how could I manage the 404 error? Could I redirect to a file without changes in the URL to manage it with your code suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

The Location object has a property that does exactly what you want:

```
window.location.pathname
```

If you don't want the initial slash, you can remove it like so:

```
window.location.pathname.substring(1)
```

Documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location

Comment: Thnx. But no file where write it, the url doesnt has ?, then redirect to the 404 error page.
Do u know how could I manage the 404 error? Could I redirect to a file without changes in the URL to manage it with your code suggestions?

Comment: That sounds like a separate question.